# Multiple Dictionaries in one MainDictionary c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview

i hope you can give me a hint for my problem i have with my code.
I have a DataGridView which got its Data from an Excelfile. 
Now to get structure in it, i want to make groups (keyword in dsdslls) and add valueNames (value of dsdslls and keyword in dslls) to that groups and add that content (value of dslls) to valueNames as KeyValuePair.

My Problem is not to add all that stuff, but to get it back.

here is the code (add stuff):

```
    internal Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, LinkedList<String>>> BuildList(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        //create the main Dictionary
        Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, LinkedList<String>>> dsdslls = new Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, LinkedList<String>>>();
        String groupName = "Project data", value = "", valueName = "", text = "";
        //run through the whole list 
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            //create new Dictionary for the Content
            Dictionary<String, LinkedList<String>> dslls = new Dictionary<String, LinkedList<String>>();
            //check if the String at i is a groupName, if so add it to groupName
            if (isGroupName(dgv, i))
            {
                groupName = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                text = "Adding in group: " + groupName + " to value: ";
            }
            //now go forward in the list until you next Cell is empty or the list ended
            do
            {
                //check if the String at i is a valueName, if so add it to valueName
                if (isValueName(dgv, i))
                {
                    //create the LinkedList for units and values
                    LinkedList<String> lls = new LinkedList<String>();
                    valueName = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    //check if group and valuename are NOT the same
                    if (isNotSame(valueName, groupName))
                    {
                        //now run the colums for units and values and add them to the List until you reach the end of used columns
                        int j = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            value = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1 + j].Value.ToString();
                            lls.AddLast(value);
                            if (j == 0)
                            {
                                text += "\n" + valueName + " in (" + lls.First.Value.ToString() + "): ";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                text += lls.Last.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            j++;
                        } while (j < dgv.Rows[i].Cells.Count - 1);
                        //add the valueName and List as new keyvaluepair to the dictionary.
                        dslls.Add(valueName, lls);
                    }
                }
                i++;
            } while (!isStringEmpty(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) && i < dgv.RowCount - 1);
            //show added content
            MessageBox.Show(text);
            //check if main dictionary contains the latest groupname, if not add the groupName and the last dictionary to the main dictionary
            if (!dsdslls.ContainsKey(groupName))
            {
                dsdslls.Add(groupName, dslls);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Building successfully finished.");
        return dsdslls;
    }
```

I'm not getting the right content back to the specified groupName... for example:" groupName = "Project Data" i got back the content of the group:" Electrical Network" which is the next keyword in the maindictionary

now the code to get the Data:

```
           internal void /*Dictionary<String, LinkedList<String>>*/ GetGroupContent(Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, LinkedList<String>>> dsdslls, String groupName)
    {
        //Dictionary<String, LinkedList<String>> dslls = new Dictionary<String, LinkedList<String>>();
        String groupN = "", text = "";
        //Check if Dictionary contains groupName
        if (dsdslls.ContainsKey(groupName))
        {
            //run through the dictionary
            foreach (var s in dsdslls)
            {
                //give back the keyword (just for the MessageBox)
                if (s.Key == groupName)
                {
                    groupN = s.Key;
                }
                else
                {
                    //run throught the little dictionary to get the keywords from it. 
                    foreach (var t in s.Value)
                    {
                        text += t.Key + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Content of Group " + groupN + ": \n" + text);
            text = "";
        }
        //return dslls;
    }
```

Kind regards

Mirko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand what you expect from this code as the main problem is not well described.

Anyway, it seems that there might be problem in your data retrieval logic.
If you want to get data of group with matching name, then you have to move `else` part of your `if` statement. You need to do text concatenation only when group with correct name is found.

```
...
//give back the keyword (just for the MessageBox)
if (s.Key == groupName)
{
    groupN = s.Key;

    //run throught the little dictionary to get the keywords from it. 
    foreach (var t in s.Value)
    {
        text += t.Key + "\n";
    }
}
...
```

Comment: to your new added question, i will create two methods, one will return the keywords of the little dictionary regarding to the groupName, and the second one will return the valueNames (keywords of the little dictionary) and values from the littleDictionary. so if the group Motor is called, i want to get back Power, ccm a.s.o. with the second i will get power 500 ps, 8.2l ccm a.s.o.